# Error with code.. Please check it out

Tags: php

I have two tables and I want to show a list items of particular table as hyperlink only if its value exist in another table. Otherwise it show value as plain text not hyperlink.

Considering example...

```
$result= mysql_query("select * from tbl_songlist_info order by song_title") or die(mysql_error());
$resultpoet= mysql_query("select * from tbl_poet_info") or die(mysql_error());
$rowpoet= mysql_fetch_array($resultpoet);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

Now I have to show values of `$row` as hyperlink only if its value exist in `$rowpoet`.. I have used in array function. please chk it out...

```
<? if (in_array($row['poet_name'],$rowpoet)) { ?>
<a href="poet.php?title=<?=$row['poet_name'] ?>"><? } ?>
<?=$row['poet_name'] ?> </a>
```

please check this code. All value are showing as plain text if value exist in other table than also...

Comment: Totally worth the checking, uh, excuse me... "chk"ing out.

Comment: Y my reputation is degraded...?

Comment: As a guess, lack of professionalism.

Comment: As I am newbie hows that possible to be professional from starting...it would surely be after sometime..

Comment: Wat about my question..?

Comment: Consider waiting more than 15s to ask another question (also consider editing!). Consider having proper English in your question, it attracts views and in turn helps you get an answer faster. Consider not doing `in_array($row['poet_name'],$rowpoet)`. Consider posting more code.

Comment: When asking a question, pretend that you are asking an oracle of infinite wisdom whom is short on time. You can only ask one question, so you better choose carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like :

```
<? if (in_array($row['poet_name'],$rowpoet)) { ?>
  <a href="poet.php?title=<?=$row['poet_name'] ?>"><?=$row['poet_name'] ?></a>
<? } else { ?>
  <?=$row['poet_name'] ?>
<? } ?>
```

unless i misunderstand that will check for 'poet_name' field inside $rowpoet array and if it exists put a link, otherwise if not in array then put plain text.

Hope that helps

Comment: still its not working bro.. Text is showing as plain text only. I think error is in IN-array function where i have matched values of two arrays.

Comment: i think actually mysql_fetch_array isn't compatible directly with in_array, try populating a single dimensional array with just the poet_name column from $resultpoet first. Something like:    while ($rowPoet = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultPoet)) {
      $poetArray[] = $rowPoet["poet_name"];
    } then use that array as the haystack